# WordPress で固定ページと投稿ページごとにCSSを設定したい。更に、固定ページはスラッグごとに、CSSを設定したいです。

Tags: php, wordpress

#### 目的と現状

期待した出力は固定ページや投稿ページに変移するごとに、それぞれのcssを読み込み、サイトをデザインしてほしい。
完成はきれいにスタイリングされている状態です。

[image: 固定ページ現状]

現状ではそれぞれのサイトのCSSが読み込まれていないです。

#### 試したこと

様々な部分で調べました。しかし、うまくいきませんでした。
調べた内容は、if構文を使って、固定ページと投稿ページで分岐させる書き方です。
解決できなかったので、ご教授ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

PHP

```
<?php if(is_single() ): ?>
    <!-- 投稿ページでは -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/asset/css/blog.css">

    <!-- //固定ページでは -->
    <?php elseif( is_page('contact') ) :?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/asset/css/conatct.css">
    <?php elseif(is_page() ) :?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/asset/css/blog.css">
    <?php else:?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/asset/css/style.css">
    <?php endif; ?>
}
```

Comment: 期待した出力結果と動作、実際の出力結果と動作、エラーが出るならエラーメッセージ、「様々な部分で調べた」ことの要約を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
期待した出力は固定ページや投稿ページに変移するごとに、それぞれのcssを読み込み、サイトをデザインしてほしい。

実際は、「それぞれのサイトのCSSが読み込まれていないです」

Answer (score 0):

何らかのテーマを修正していると思いますが

テーマフォルダ内の　各ページを表示しているテーマファイルにCSSなどを設定しないと反映されないと思います。（*テーマフォルダにindex.phpしかないなら、条件分岐で指定しますが、*）

一例ですが、
投稿記事なら、single.php テーマファイル
投稿記事一覧なら、　archive.php テーマファイル
を追加修正します。

各テーマファイルについては以下を見てください。
https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/wiki/images/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg
https://ja.wordpress.org/support/article/using-themes/

*追伸、アクテブでないテーマを誤って修正していると反映されません。*

自身でデバッグしていると思いますが
一部抜粋phpコードの一番下に

```
}
```

が有るのですが、もしかして以下の様に styleの定義の中に入れ子になっていませんか？
linkタグが styleの定義として解釈され無視されているかもしれません。
chromeの”要素の検証”などで、どの様にhtmlが出力されているか確認することを勧めます。

```
  <style>
   .何ちゃらclass {
       display: none;
<?php if(is_single() ): ?>
    <!-- 投稿ページでは -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/asset/css/blog.css">

    <!-- //固定ページでは -->
    <?php elseif( is_page('contact') ) :?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/asset/css/conatct.css">
    <?php elseif(is_page() ) :?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/asset/css/blog.css">
    <?php else:?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/asset/css/style.css">
    <?php endif; ?>
              }
  </style>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。因みに、テーマフォルダーごとにCSSを書かないといけない理由は何ですか？

Comment: 上記を聞いた理由は理屈がわからないと、どこを修正したらよいか、判断がつかないからです。一度テーマごとにCSSを設定しましたが、できませんでした。

上記のif文を使ったコードを書いたのは下記の記事を見たからです。

Comment: 基本、cssはインラインスタイル以外は、<head> 要素にcssを定義（読み込み）しないと反映されないと思います。ページ毎に個別のスタイルを読み込みたいなら、表示するテンプレートファイルに定義するのが一番素直だと思い回答しています。

Comment: なるほどです。ご回答ありがとうございます。私のphpファイルはheaderを共通なので,header内のheadに書いていました。これで反映させるために、上記のような書き方(if構文)で書きました。文法上は正しいと思いますがいかがでしょうか。？

Comment: もう一度、phpからの出力内容などを確認して見ることを勧めます。styleが反映されない可能性を回答に追加しました。

Answer (score 0):

`is_page()`ではなく`$post->post_name`でスラッグは取得できますので、分岐できるはずです。
ただ、head内にlinkタグを直書きで出力するよりも、`functions.php`に`wp_enqueue_scripts`を`add_action`して、`wp_enqueue_style`を使って出力するのが正しいと思います。

わけがわからないかもしれませんが、とりあえず`wp_enqueue_scripts`と`wp_enqueue_style`を調べてみるといいです。`$post->post_name`もですね。

`wp_enqueue_scripts`を`add_action`させる関数内で、`$post->post_name`を使って分岐させればできるはずです。

ですが、もっと簡単なのは、CSSファイルの出力を分けるよりも、`class`や`id`などでページごとのセレクターを当てて分岐するのが早いです。
wordpressは`body`にページごとの`class`を付与してくれています。もちろん付与することも可能ですのでぜひ試してみてください。